# Why in 'Windows Terminal' in some color schemes black color matches the background color?

Tags: colors, windows-terminal, color-theme

I use the "Windows Terminal" in the "Windows 10" system. Recently I noticed that in some command line applications, parts of messages disappear.

It turned out that the authors of some command-line applications, for example, output messages to the console in different colors, including black. At the same time, in some 'Windows Terminal' color schemes, the black color matches the background color. Because of this, black color text merge with the background and 'disappear'.

Example 1. Color Scheme: `Campbell`, Black: `#0C0C0C`, Background: `#0C0C0C`. Some HTML elements are **not visible**:

[image: Illustration 1]

Example 2. Color Scheme: `One Half Dark`, Black: `#282C34`, Background: `#282C34`. Some HTML elements are **not visible**:

[image: Illustration 2]

Example 3. Color Scheme: `Campbell Powershell`, Black: `#0C0C0C`, Background: `#012456`. All HTML elements are **visible**:

[image: Illustration 3]

My questions:

1. What would be more correct: the application developer should not use black color in his application, or should the user change the color scheme of the 'Windows Terminal'?

(In the first case, I will write a issue to the developer on 'GitHub', in the second case I will make a correction to the 'Windows Terminal' color scheme myself.)

2. If the color scheme should be changed, then why did the author of the color scheme create a match of black and background? Is there an objective reason or is it a mistake?

(I know how to change the color scheme, that's not the question.)

**Addition**. In 'Windows Terminal', the color scheme setting includes 16 terminal colors slots (black, red, green, yellow, blue, purple, cyan, white; each of them is bright and dark, it turns out 16 in total) and 4 system color slots (foreground color, background color, cursor color, selection background color). Here's what it looks like:

[image: Color schemes]

The question is about color slots (black color slot and background color slot). As I understand it, the developer manipulates the slots, and the real colors are set by the color scheme. This is where the conflict is born.

It seems to me that if the color scheme sets different values in all these 20 slots, then the text will not 'disappear' in any case. Since if all the colors are different, then none of them will be able to blend with the other. The only question is why the authors of color schemes do not do this.

**Addition 2**. [@zadjii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903987/why-in-windows-terminal-in-some-color-schemes-black-color-matches-the-backgrou#comment128777797_72903987) wrote that

> Before 2018, the Windows console didn't support a separate background color at all. The BG had to be one of the 16 colors of the color table (usually black). Hence why Campbell (the refreshed color scheme for the console) doesn't have a separate BG value.

If this is the case, then the answer is that the coincidence of black and background color is a relic of an outdated programs.

Comment: Developers are failing to set a different background color when black is used - the only way I know to resolve this is changing the terminal's background color or assigning the black color a different hex and manually changing the terminal background to hex `000000`. `wt` is highly customizable, albeit I prefer [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) since it thismakes customization simple via its Settings _(if you choose to try it, [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/ConEmu/ConEmu.xml) is the custom pre-built settings profile I use, imported via Settings)_

Comment: @JW0914 Does 'ConEmu' work on the basis of 'Windows Console' (conhost.exe)?

Comment: @JW0914 In your XML: what does the `<value name="BackColorIdx" type="hex" data="00"/>` mean? I think it means that 'BackColorIdx' is the same as 'ColorTable00'. Am I right? This is the same problem I asked the question about.

Comment: This website is meant for specific questions that can be answered objectively without debate. Your question invites debate and you have asked multiple questions too. On the answers and edits that have been made so far you ask even further questions and seem to be shifting your criteria for a "correct" answer. I think you need to rewrite your question to be more focused and not be open to opinion based answers.

Comment: @Romen You're right, my question is 'floating'. For a clear question I can find the answer myself. I am asking the community for an answer to a difficult question that I can hardly formulate. I'm sorry you deleted your answer. I was taught to seek the truth by asking a lot of questions to myself and others. So I'm asking a lot of questions, it's not directed against you. If I have violated the rules of the site, let the administrators delete my question.

Comment: I only deleted my answer so I could try again after you have focused the question to something specific that can be answered objectively. I felt that my answer was too opinion based and could not be backed up by sources so it felt like a low quality answer to an unfocused question.

Comment: I think maybe the most interesting and focused questions you've asked so far (paraphrased) are *"Are there any rules or guidelines for creating default terminal themes?"* and similarly, *"Are there any rules or guidelines for command line programs that specify how the terminal colors should be used?"* -- I think both of these questions go together and can be answered with *"Yes. Here is this source documenting it ...."* if anything like that exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Why in 'Windows Terminal' in some color schemes black color matches the background color?**

At the dawn of the existence of terminals, they were physical devices, not terminal emulators, as they are now. Back then, the color palette of terminals was often determined by the terminal manufacturer. In many terminals, [3 bits were assigned to the color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_8-bit_computer_hardware_graphics). In the RGB color model, each of these 3 bits corresponded to its component: R, G and B. It turned out the following:

```
000 #000000 black
001 #0000ff blue
010 #00ff00 green
011 #00ffff cyan
100 #ff0000 red
101 #ff00ff magenta
110 #ffff00 yellow
111 #ffffff white
```

In terminals with this implementation of the color palette, only 8 colors were available. The default background color and the default text color could be selected by the terminal user only one of these colors. Black and white colors were most suitable for this role, since they are the pair of colors with the highest contrast ([21:1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-contrast-ratio)). Therefore, they usually configured it like this:

```
000 #000000 black   (default background)
001 #0000ff blue
010 #00ff00 green
011 #00ffff cyan
100 #ff0000 red
101 #ff00ff magenta
110 #ffff00 yellow
111 #ffffff white   (default foreground)
```

This scheme was fixed in the [ECMA-48 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) (late 1970s), later passed into terminal emulator programs and has survived to this day.

Until now, there are many terminal emulator programs that implement a palette of 16 colors, and the default background color and default text color are chosen from these 16 colors:

```
black   (default background)  |  bright (bold) black
blue                          |  bright (bold) blue
green                         |  bright (bold) green
cyan                          |  bright (bold) cyan
red                           |  bright (bold) red
magenta                       |  bright (bold) magenta
yellow                        |  bright (bold) yellow
white   (default foreground)  |  bright (bold) white
```

Most color schemes have this palette in mind.

In many modern terminal emulators (including "Windows Terminal") it has become fashionable to add additional slots to the palette of 16 colors. For example, in the Windows Terminal program (a palette of 18 slots):

```
black    |  bright (bold) black    |  default background
blue     |  bright (bold) blue     |  default foreground
green    |  bright (bold) green    |
cyan     |  bright (bold) cyan     |
red      |  bright (bold) red      |
magenta  |  bright (bold) magenta  |
yellow   |  bright (bold) yellow   |
white    |  bright (bold) white    |
```

People are taking old system color schemes and converting them to 'Windows Terminal' color schemes. Therefore, it turns out that 'black' matches the 'default background' and 'white' matches the 'default foreground'. I think we need to wait until the authors of the color schemes realize that new slots should be taken into account in the color schemes for new programs. IMHO: the new color schemes should not match 'black' with 'default background' and 'white' with 'default foreground'.

**What would be more correct: the application developer should not use black color in his application, or should the user change the color scheme of the 'Windows Terminal'?**

There is no fixed set of rules for this. Each party may voluntarily make efforts to ensure that text and background colors do not match.

As a console application developer, I would recommend avoiding "dangerous combinations" of slots in your program. Not recommended:

- 'black' text on 'default background'
- 'default foreground' text on 'white' background

I would recommend that the author of the color scheme for the 'Windows Terminal' program consider additional slots in the palette of this program. Avoid matching 'black' with 'default background' and 'white' with 'default foreground'.